# Finding first integrals of $\frac{dx}{1}=-\frac{dy}{y+2z}=\frac{dz}{3y+4z}$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I found one first integral by deriving
$$dx=\frac{dz+dy}{2z+2y}.$$
Hence $$d(2x-\ln|z+y|)=0$$
I wish to exponenciate above first integral to get more plesent one
$$(z+y)e^{-2x}=C_1$$
Can I do so? And how to find second first integral?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint :** Take last two ratios and find a relation between $y$ and $z$.
$$\frac{\,dy}{\,dz}=-\frac{y+2z}{3y+4z}.$$Now , put $y=vz$ and solve.

Comment: Solve it for $v$? I do not understand what that whould give me.

Comment: @Fallen Apart ) Sorry I can't help you...Because you don't know the basic thing in differential equation.

Comment: If you don't know how to solve the homogeneous equation of first order then how you want to solve simultaneous equation ? strange !!